# What is multiplex socket communication?

Tags: java, sockets, terminology, tcp

I searched the "*multiplex socket*" on internet, but couldn’t found out the **difference** between multiplex socket and normal socket behaviors.

Normal socket also can communicate on both directions (read and write stream).

I think I must understand wrong about concept of multiplex, welcome your opinion about multiplex communication, Thanks!

EDIT: I use Java to implement the multiplex socket.

Comment: wheres java in this question?:D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, Multiplex communication is the sharing of a small number of sockets (e.g. one) to pass data for multiple higher level streams e.g. topics or queues.

Comment: Yes, "sharing of a small number of sockets" is a requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Multiplexing is running multiple connections over one socket, all messages for those connections will be received on that socket (or send). So it's not two-way communication, but multiple different communication channels that are handled by one socket.

Comment: +0: You can run multiple connections two way. ;)

Comment: Do you mean that two-way communication works in sequence of: “send -> receive -> send -> receive…”. While multiplex doesn’t have such sequence?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. However instead of trying to rephrase it, both Peter Lawrey and Sarnold explain it better than me atm :). (@ Peter Lawrey, I mean two-way communication, it reads a bit weird but I meant or not xor (too bad English doesnt work that way :P).

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find the reference to `multiplex socket`? I can think of two answers:

First, using a single UDP `socket()` and `recvfrom(2)` to receive packets from multiple clients. (One possibility would be the BIND DNS server in recursive mode; older versions used a single socket, rather than `connect(2)`ing a new socket for every client.)

Second, using a single connection to multiplex several channels into one stream; this is done by e.g. `ssh(1)` when you ask it for `-X` X11 forwarding or `-L` or `-R` port-forwarding. You can send data bound for the terminal, or an X server, or remote ports, all over a *single* TCP session.

Comment: https://idea.popcount.org/2016-11-01-a-brief-history-of-select2/